# Issue with UTL_MAIL Oracle

Tags: oracle, smtp, oracle11g

I'm trying to send email using `oracle 11g` as below.

```
begin
  utl_mail.send(
  sender     => 'user@xxx.com',
  recipients => 'user@gmail.com',
  message    => 'Hello World'
  );
```

but i got below error.

```
ORA-29279: SMTP permanent error: 530 5.5.1 http://support.google.com/mail/bin/answer.py?answer=14257 ph1sm17301835pbb.45
ORA-06512: at "SYS.UTL_MAIL", line 654
ORA-06512: at "SYS.UTL_MAIL", line 671
ORA-06512: at line 2
29279. 00000 -  "SMTP permanent error: %s"
*Cause:    A SMTP permanent error occurred.
*Action:   Correct the error and retry the SMTP operation.
```

how could i solve this ?

Comment: What server are you connecting to? Can you open a connection via telnet <servername> 25?

Comment: @FrankSchmitt to Google SMTP Server

Comment: What happens if you try telnet smtp.gmail.com 25 from your database server? Do you get a connection?

Comment: @FrankSchmitt yes. i got a connection.

Comment: BTW, your post title is misleading, since you're using utl_mail and not utl_smtp (although you'll have to switch to utl_smtp anyway, see my answer).

Answer (score 3):

According to the [GMail documentation](http://support.google.com/mail/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=13287), you need SMTP/Auth to send E-Mails via GMail.

Unfortunately, utl_mail doesn't support this - you'll have to use utl_smtp.

See [Oracle Forums](https://forums.oracle.com/forums/thread.jspa?threadID=288758) for an example.